# VB Microsoft.ace.oledb.12.0' provider is not registered

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012

I have the famous error :

```
microsoft.ace.oledb.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine.
```

I devlopped the program with a 32 bits System using visual studio 2013 and visual studio 2010 and Office 2010.

when I run my program from a 64 bits system. I have the error.
I tried many solutions including :

- changing the target to Any CPU
- installing  the access database engine 2007:
  http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=23734
- and 2010 redistributable:
  http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255

but it still not working

Please Help

Comment: Did you include the .NET reference `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access 12.0.0.0` in your project?

Comment: Yes I added it but 'Copy Local' is false(hidden)